# Parallel Aggregation with postgres insert/copy locking and blocking

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, locking, bulkinsert, blocking

I need to do a big amount of calculation, then insert the result to postgres database. I used parallel aggregation to do the calculation and shard it by the processor count.

I noticed for each cycle, the first 5 mins, cpu utilization is 100% as all cores are doing the calculation. Then the next 30 mins, all the data are copied into postgres by different threads, which blocks each other... Wondering what I should do to optimize it. Sharding is not really an option here, as we are already partition the table by date, don't want to make it too complicated by sharding it again by PersonId...

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Is it possible to put the data into a single queue and let postgres to process the queue?

More details:
In each thread, it does 2 things: 
1) calls a data service to do the calculation, and get back the result set 
2) Copy the result set into a database table(Kpis_weekly)

We start N (N = processor count) threads to do the above process, the data is sharded by personId so they are spread roughly evenly over all the threads. The bottle neck is the database table. All these threads have to insert into the same table, therefore they block each other and slow down the whole thing.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to go on. How, where and why are the threads copying into PostgreSQL blocking each other? Details!

Answer (score 0):

The issue (as `OP` rightly pointed out) is that funneling all writes that the thread generate to one single table is probably the bottleneck.

What we do here is that despite using `PARTITION` (which mainly assists in reads / `SELECT` statements) the writes are `NOT` trigger oriented. So yes, that 'does' mean moving the logic of generating table names to the threads, but for us, that is 'really' worth the effort.

So for e.g. the following code writes directly to child tables (instead of the parent tables) but importantly the writes are effectively parallelized. Obviously the writes are I/O bound, so faster the disks, faster the writes. The following SQL was effectively using parallel threads (even for writes) and not a DB bottleneck (but an Disk-Subsystem one).

#### SQL

```
create UNLOGGED table p(a integer);
create UNLOGGED table c1() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c2() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c3() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c4() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c5() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c6() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c7() INHERITS (p);
create UNLOGGED table c8() INHERITS (p);
```

#### via shell script

```
psql -c "INSERT INTO c1 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c2 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c3 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c4 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c5 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c6 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c7 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
psql -c "INSERT INTO c8 select a from generate_series (1,10000000) as e(a);" &
```

After `INSERT`, you may want to convert them to LOGGED tables (**PostgreSQL 9.5+**) like this, for all (child+parent) tables:

`ALTER TABLE p SET LOGGED;`